# Cannot resolve module 'imaplib2' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

There are many questions regarding `imaplib2 has no attribute IMAP4_SSL` but none of the solutions in the other questions worked for me.

I have a python script that's been running without issue for years on AWS, but after I upgraded to `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`, it started throwing the error about `IMAP4_SSL`. After looking into the issue, I believe it may have something to do with the mappings in Python, but it all looks correct to me. I also checked that there are no other Python versions installed that could cause a conflict.

Here are the paths for Python and the `imaplib2` package

```bash
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5

$ whereis python3
'/usr/bin/python3.8-config'
'/usr/bin/python3'
'/usr/bin/python3.8'
'/usr/lib/python3'
'/usr/lib/python3.8'
'/usr/lib/python3.9'
'/etc/python3'
'/etc/python3.8'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8'
'/usr/include/python3.8'
'/usr/share/python3'
'/usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz'

$ sys.path
''
'/usr/lib/python38.zip'
'/usr/lib/python3.8'
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload'
'/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages'
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
```

```python
> import imaplib2
> imaplib2.__file__
'/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imaplib2/__init__.py'
```

Comment: Are you asking about `imaplib` or `imaplib2`? If you are asking about `imaplib2`, how did you install it? The [version on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/imaplib2/) is pretty outdated and seems to have this problem. On Ubuntu, you can install a newer version by installing the `python3-imaplib2` package.

Comment: I am asking about `imaplib2`. I've fixed the question. Thanks for that. How do I use `python3-imaplib2`? I used `apt` to install it but then what?

Comment: You also probably need to uninstall the PyPI version since your `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` directory is earlier in your `PYTHONPATH` than your `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` directory. You should be able to do that by running `python3 -m pip uninstall imaplib2`.

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I will organize my comments as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using an outdated version of `imaplib2` from PyPI. You can install a newer version on Ubuntu using the following command.

```sh
sudo apt install python3-imaplib2
```

(Alternatively, if you are not on Ubuntu, you can always install [from source](https://github.com/jazzband/imaplib2).)

Depending on your `PYTHONPATH` and the location where you installed the old version of `imaplib2`, you may also need to uninstall the old version using `pip` before `import imaplib2` will import the right version.

```sh
python3 -m pip uninstall imaplib2
```